# UITableView with Event Handler

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin, mono, xamarin.ios

So in my app I'm using a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell to display a list of 'CustomItems' that contains a UISegmentedControl as an On/Off switch. Changing the value of a UISegmentedControl in cell 2, should turn on/off CustomItem[2], etc.

The UISegmentedControl performs an action for a CustomItem when the value is changed in a worker thread. The code I have works fine 99% of the time - in fact I have never seen it misbehaving. However we have customers who have reported that the UISegemented control is SOMETIMES not controlling the correct item.

In my UITableViewSource 'GetCell()' method, I have code that looks similar to this:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
   var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as CustomCell ?? new CustomCell(cellIdentifier);

   . . .

   // Handle the UISegementedControl (On/Off switch) value changed event
   cell.segmentControl.ValueChanged += delegate
   {
      // Do some stuff 
      cell.outputControl.TintColor = cell.outputControl.SelectedSegment == 0 ? UIColor.Gray : UIColor.Red;
      var currentItem = tableItems[cell.IndexPath.Row];
      TurnSomethingOnOrOff(currentItem);
   }
}

private void TurnSomethingOnOrOff(CustomItem currentItem)
{
   var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
      // turn currentItem on or off
   };
   worker.RunWorkerAsync ();
}
```

What the user is seeing is that, on occasion, changing the value of the UISegementedControl in cell 1, is turning both CustomItem[0] and CustomItem[1] on or off.

I'm not sure how to get my app into the state that my customer is able to (they're not entirely sure either, it seems to happen at random).

Could this be something to do with Garbage Collection or some other reason why my cells would be losing the correct Event Handler?

The list only has 2 or 3 items in it, so cells generally aren't being reused. I did test the cell reuse (by scrolling off screen so the cells have to be redisplayed), and all that happened was the ValueChanged event is triggered twice, but the wrong event was never triggered.

Comment: Have you checked if is due to the cell reuse?

Comment: When the cells are being reused, all that I've made happen is that the events are triggered multiple times, but never the wrong event :/